# Multiple passwords for mail accounts used by multiple users?

Tags: email, imap, mail-server

Are there any mail servers that allow multiple users to access the same mail account, but each of the users with their own, specific password?

The goal is that access to a shared mail account can be granted and revoked without everybody having to change passwords in their mail clients when access rights need to be revoked from one user.

Comment: Since the username/password are properties of an account, I think what you're looking for is to have multiple _accounts_ access the same _mailbox_ (or folder).

Comment: Which should just be permission management. Shared mailboxes are a standard feature of e.g. Exchange.

Comment: @user1686 That's interesting – can you point me to any examples how to share specific folders of an (IMAP) mailbox? Or did I misunderstand what you were saying?